# Showing that this expression has positive values for positive values for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To show:

$e^x(x-1)+1 \gt 0$ (always positive for positive values of $x$)

I can understand it will hold for values greater than one but what about the real numbers between
$0 \lt x\lt 1$?

Comment: Show that $f(x)=e^x(x-1)+1$ is strictly increasing in $(0,+\infty)$

Comment: $e^{x} >1+x$ for $x >0$. Can you use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by Taylor series, $e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{\zeta^2}2$ for $\zeta$  between $0$ and $x$.

Hence if $x \ne 0$, $$1-x<e^{-x},$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^x$ ,

$$e^x(1-x) < 1.$$

Hence the result in fact hold for any non-zero $x$.